# is there a way I can retrieve an ics file using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, icalendar

I'm looking to create a read-only calendar on my website based on a users calendar (google, outlook, iCal, etc). In order to do this, I figured I would need to make a call to get/create an ics file. Is this possible to do in javascript/jquery? Thanks

Comment: You can get any file with ajax ***as long as it is on your server*** !

Comment: Thanks for responding. Is there a way if it's not on my server?

Comment: serverside code can get any file on the web

Comment: could you please give me an example or maybe provide a link? thanks

Comment: In PHP it would be `file_get_contents('http://url/somefile.html');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create files on your own server, you'll need server-side code to do this. If you'd like to get files from your own server, you can use JavaScript, though if you'd like to get files from other servers, you'll need to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Another possible solution is to keep the calendar stored in a cloud-based calendar service (like Google Calendar), and then use that service's API to work with the calendar. Google has a [JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/) you can use for accessing Google Calendar, that might help you out.